# UML class diagram - how to show that one class includes another

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have a situation similar to this:

```
classA.h:
class A{};

classB.h:
#include "classA.h"
class B{};
```

Is there a way (and should I do it?) to show that classB uses (includes) classA even though there is no heredity involved? ClassB doesn't even have classA as a member, but I feel like it would make sense to somehow show this in the class diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it two ways. The first is to simply enlarge `B` so it can hold `A` like this:

[image]

Note the fully qualified name for `A`.

Another way is to use an `import` relation:

[image]